# get_or_create() creating a new object everytime I run the test case

Tags: python, django, web-api-testing

I am testing my api and everytime am running the test case using **python manage.py test api.users.tests --keepdb** it is creating a new Language object everytime, instead it should fetch the existing Language object itself as I am not destroying the database.

```
class ProfileTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        instance, is_created = Language.objects.get_or_create(value='English', locale='en')
        url = '/api/v1/auth/login/'
        data = {'mobile_number': '9899137678', 'country_code': '91', 'device_id': '123'}
        response = Client().post(path=url, data=data)
        json_response = response.json()
        url = '/api/v1/auth/verify/'
        data = {'code': json_response['otp'],
                'verification_id': json_response['verification_id'],
                'language': instance.id,
                'registration_id': '123',
                'type': '1',
                'device_id': json_response['device_id']}
        response = Client().post(path=url, data=data)
        json_response = response.json()
        token = json_response['token']['access']
        token = 'Token ' + token
        cls.headers = {
            'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': token,
        }


    def test_get_user_profile(self):
        url = '/api/v1/users/profile/'
        response = self.client.get(path=url, **self.headers)
        print('\n', response.content, '\n')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK, 'Couldn\'t fetch profile data.')
```

Comment: are you sure  check with `True` assertion with `is_created`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I have checked that by using the print() statement. It is printing a new object id everytime.